# Python GDAL Warp netcdf creating NaN values at 360 longitude

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

When I attempt to use GDAL warp to reproject from 1.875x1.25 to 0.5x0.5 res NaN values are produced at the 360 longitude mark. The data is in NetCDF format. Using average or mode resampling algorithm produces 1 set of NaN results, with any other algorithm producing 2. The rest of the warp works as expected.

Gdal warp command used:

```
    region = [0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 20.0]
    warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(outputBounds=region, xRes = 0.5, yRes = 0.5, dstSRS='EPSG:4326', format = 'netcdf', copyMetadata=True, outputBoundsSRS='EPSG:4326', resampleAlg = gdal.GRA_Average)
    gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS='/examplefile.nc', srcDSOrSrcDSTab='outputfile.nc', options=warp_options)
```

Input data:
[image]

[image]

Result using average algorithm
[image]
[image]

Result using default algorithm:
[image]
[image]

No error messages are produced. Is there a problem with my code or is it a problem with the warp tool? Is there a known workaround for this problem?

Comment: What is the "region" variable?

Comment: @guillermo_dangelo Sorry I should have included that currently its set to: region = [0.0, 0.0, 360.0, 20.0]

Comment: look at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/6482

Answer (score 0):

Would't your region parameter be something like this?:

```
region = [-180, -90, 180, 20]
```

Comment: I originally assumed so but that produced data only with a longitude greater than 0.  Whereas the method I used covered the full -180 to 180